# How do I transfer data in php to javascript with while loop

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

How can I use multiple markers? this code show only one marker.

I know I need to use loop but how?

This code puts the marker with information from the database on Google Maps

My problem is that once you put the marker on the screen, the other markers in the database do not come.

```
<?php
$connectmaps=$db->prepare("select title,longt,latit,description from pages where onmap = 1");
$connectmaps->execute();
$loadmaps=$connectmaps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$loadmap_json = json_encode($loadmaps);
?>

<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
        // Google Maps
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize&key=MY_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
    function initialize() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };
        // Sayfada Haritayı Göster
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);


        // Multiple Markers
        var phpden = <?php echo $loadmap_json; ?>;
        var longt= parseFloat(phpden.longt)
        var title= phpden.title
        var description = phpden.description
        var boylam = parseFloat(phpden.latit)

        var markers = [ 
            [title, longt, latit],
        ];
        // İnfo Windows
        var infoWindowContent = [
            ['<div class="info_content">' + '<h3>' + title+ '</h3>' + '<p>' + description + '</p>' + '</div>' + ''],
        ];


        // Show multiple markers
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
        // İşaretçi Dizisini Döngüye Sok ve Harita Üzerine Yerleştir
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
            // Tüm İşaretçileri Otomatik Olarak Ekrana Sığdır
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `$loadmaps=$connectmaps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` by itself will only fetch the first record of your resultset, therefore, you will likely need to loop through the resultset and append each result to an array, e.g.

```
$mapMarkers = [];
while($marker=$connectmaps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
   array_push($mapMarkers, $marker);
}
$loadmap_json = json_encode($mapMarkers);
```

You'll also need to modify your javascript to expect an array of markers, as your current code expects a single result. You should also anticipate the possibility of no results (empty JSON array).

```
for(var i = 0; i < phpden.length(); i++) {
 //Do you process of each marker here... e.g. phpden[i].longt
 //Or better... create a function that you call for each marker to add them
}
```

Just a final suggestion, but as in the above, you should consider using more descriptive variable names. Not just for others if you are working in a team, but for yourself. Abbreviated and unrelated named variables make your code harder to understand. When you come back later after your complexity has increased, you or someone else will waste time trying to figure out what "phpden" and a "boylam" are.

Comment: @zemarkhos Just wanted to note that the line using `fetchAll()` from @miken32 answer below would be better than the `for() {fetch()}` loop I included for just collecting data. However, one caveat is that if you need to modify/add/calculate data prior to converting to json, you would need the `for()` loop. In this instance, `fetchAll()` will likely be better/faster.

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch()` method is only fetching the first record. Instead, use the `fetchAll()` method. This will give you a multidimensional array of every record in the set.

Also note, ***if you aren't passing any variables into your query***, PDO does have a `query()` method; no need to prepare and execute.

```
<?php
$connectmaps = $db->query(
    "SELECT title, longt, latit, description FROM pages WHERE onmap = 1"
);
$loadmaps = $connectmaps->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$loadmaps_json = json_encode($loadmaps);
```